# Expectation of transformation of two random variables

Tags: probability

$X, Y$ are two independent random variables. I want to calculate:

$$E\Big[\frac{e^{-X}}{1+e^{-X-Y}}\Big]$$

Is that the right formula?

$$\int \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x-y}}f(x)f(y)dxdy$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  If the expectation of the expression exists then:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E\left[\frac{e^{−X}}{ 1+e^{−X−Y}}\right] \;& \mathop{=}^{\text{def}}\;\iint_{\Bbb R^2} \frac{e^{−x}}{ 1+e^{−x−y}} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y
\\[1ex] & \mathop{=}^{\text{ind}} \iint_{\Bbb R^2} \frac{e^{−x}}{ 1+e^{−x−y}} f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y
\end{align}$$

Comment: Actually $\mathop{=}^{\text{def}}$ is not a definition, but this does not matter here.